# How to get the original case of element names in (X)HTML DOM in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom, xhtml

I read that HTML is always turned all upper case from both Node.prototype.nodeName and HTMLElement.prototype.tagName but that XML elements that are not HTML are left in their original case.

This is not what I find. Everything is turned into all caps, screaming "WE REMAIN IN THE 1980S!" into our face.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
const e = document.createElement('fooBar');
document.firstElementChild.insertBefore(e, document.firstElementChild.firstElementChild);
    </script>
    <p>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <script>       document.currentScript.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText = e.nodeName + " (" + e.namespaceURI + ")";
      </script>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the real truth now?

How can I recover the original case?

How can I preserve case?

I know I can create a `new Document()` and then the nodes I create therein remain case-sensitive.

I thought if I declared the HTML document as XHTML it should be lower case and preserve case. How can I preserve XML's case inside an HTML DOM?

---

**UPDATE**

Even though this question is *almost* answered, there is still a peculiar observation here, this is from the Chrome console

```
t = document.createElement('test')
<test>​</test>​

t.namespaceURI
'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'

u = document.createElement('TEST')
<test>​</test>​

v = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, t.nodeName)
<TEST>​</TEST>​

w = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'test')
<test>​</test>​

x = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'TEST')
<TEST>​</TEST>​

y = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'Test')
<Test>​</Test>​

z = document.createElementNS('s', 'Test')
<Test>​</Test>​

[t, u, v, w, x, y, z].map(e => e.nodeName)
(7) ['TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'Test']
```

Notice that while supposedly Chrome is unable to tell what the case of the tag name was when in the XHTML namespace it actually DOES suddenly know it in its own internal display of the tree. Yet I cannot find *how* it can do that since there appears to be no method or getter to find the original case.

Here is the same from the Firefox console which is not able to do what Chrome seems to be able to do:

```
t = document.createElement('test')
<test>

t.namespaceURI
"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

u = document.createElement('TEST')
<test>

v = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, t.nodeName)
<test>

w = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'test')
<test>

x = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'TEST')
<test>

y = document.createElementNS(t.namespaceURI, 'Test')
<test>

z = document.createElementNS('s', 'Test')
<Test>

[t, u, v, w, x, y, z].map(e => e.nodeName)
Array(7) [ "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "TEST", "Test" ]
```

So, while Firefox matches the answer I selected, Chrome has some extra quirk to still get to the original spelling.

Comment: Creating a non-standard element and dropping it into an HTML DOM does not make it an XML element.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It is likely that the highly contrived example you provided isn't a good representation of the actual problem. Please focus on the actual problem instead.

Comment: @Quentin you are simply wrong. Since XHTML is XML, any element, standard or non-standard is an XML element. A very simple question with a very simple answer. Making it an "XY problem" says more about the maker than the problem.

Comment: The document in the live demo in your question **isn't** an XHTML document. It is served with a `text/html` content-type, not an `application/xhtml+xml` content-type.

Comment: @Quentin, wrong. As you can see in the snippet now, the namespaceURI is the XHTML namespace. Note, I didn't change anything, just reveal the namespace URI

Comment: That doesn’t demonstrate that the markup was parsed using XML parsing rules in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin doesn't matter, it *is* an XML DOM now. There is no namespaceURI without it being XML.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element is not an HTML element. So use `createElementNS` instead of `createElement`. The namespace must not be the HTML namespace. The empty string will do.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
const e = document.createElementNS('', 'fooBar');
document.firstElementChild.insertBefore(e, document.firstElementChild.firstElementChild);
    </script>
    <p>
      <span>Hello</span>
      <script>
         document.currentScript.parentElement.firstElementChild.innerText = e.nodeName;
      </script>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer. Simple, clear, straigh.t-forward. I now understand that it's not about whether or not the element is valid HTML, what matters is that it is in the XHTML namespace or not.

Comment: I have taken the chosen answer checkmark off just one more time, since I could prove your answer but found that Chrome appears to have some way of remembering the original case (I had noted that in my real life case, which is why I checked on that specifically.)

Comment: @GuntherSchadow - The conversion to uppercase is a DOM API, and DOM serialization requirement. It says nothing about how it is stored internally. But since the only programmatic access you have is via those interfaces, you cannot retrieve that information.